# How to say "Kiss up, kick down" in French?

Tags: expressions, traduction

How would you translate the phrase “[kiss up, kick down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_up_kick_down)” in French?

Comment: @subsexdexter this should be an answer, as it is the only one near the meaning desired

Answer (score 8):

I can't think of an exact translation, but you may find some phrases or expressions that convey the same idea, albeit partially.

Un *petit chef* is typically a low-rank leader or manager who acts tyrannically with their subordinates.

Un *lèche-bottes* (or more vulgar: *lèche-cul*) is someone who flatters their superiors in order to gain their favors.

Depending on the context, one could combine the two, eg:

> Avec ses collègues, il joue au petit chef, mais avec ses supérieurs, c'est un vrai lèche-botte.

Or simply:

> Un petit chef lèche-bottes

Comment: En effet, on peut imaginer une description qui dirait par exemple "avec ses collègues,  il joue au petit chef,  mais avec ses supérieurs,  c'est un vrai lèche-botte".

Answer (score 1):

Some reflections on the term "to kiss up to" and its translation into French will be found in the present answer; the other term, "to kick down", seems to occur very little in translations into French and I have no understanding of it.

If we consider sample translations from the reverso, which are I think, representative of what is put in this term, we see that there is no single rendering of "to kiss up to"; it all depends on the context. (The adverbial particle denotes an event that is prevalent or in a continuing state, an event that goes on (Oxford dictionary))

1. I don't want to kiss up to you. _ Je ne veux pas vous **conforter**.
2. I thought it was to kiss up to me. _ Je pensais que c'était pour vous **la jouer** devant moi.
3. I didn't kiss up to anybody. _ Je n'ai **fait de lèche** à personne.
4. I did not kiss up to anybody. _ Je ne **cirais les pompes** de personne.
5. We'll have to kiss up to the old lady. _ Il faut **être très gentils** avec la vieille.
6. Why do you always kiss up to him? _ Pourquoi lui fais-tu de la lèche comme ça ?
7. What, and cut off the oxygen to my brain just to kiss up to some fat cats? _ 
   Quoi, et priver mon cerveau d'oxygène pour **faire plaisir** à des huiles ?
8. Why would I need to kiss up to you? _ Pourquoi aurais-je besoin de me la jouer devant toi ?
9. So if you don't kiss up to Joe and Larry first you'll end up like the ex-Ms. Giuliani. _ Si tu ne **vas pas vers** Joe et Larry **en premier**, tu vas finir comme l'ex Mme Giuliani.
10. You better let me kiss up to the architect. _ Laissez-moi **flatter** l'architecte.
11. They're "acquaintances." People I have to kiss up to due to their "leverage" potential. _ Des gens que je **dois côtoyer** parce qu'ils peuvent créer un gros "leverage".
12. You can **kiss up** to her in Polish. _ Vous l'amadouerez avec votre polonais.

"Conforter" (to confort) seems to be an extreme in the possible meanings; then, "**Faire les premiers pas** (to take the first step)"  and  "**être gentil** (to be nice to)" or "faire plaisir" are other possibilities; then  "**flatter** (to flatter)" is also conceivable; it reaches finally what is comparatively an extreme in the term "**faire de la lèche**" or just as vulgar "**lécher les bottes (à quelqu'un)** (to kiss someone's bum)", this last verbal expression meaning in decent language "to flatter in an obsequious or servile manner". Finally, there is no more involved in what the expression is reckoned sometimes to communicate than a necessity to tolerate people (**devoir cotoyer**). 
It appears that the meaning of this neologism, that is its English meaning, hasn't been settled yet or that it is one of those general purpose expressions that'll be forever, as it stand, more than a difficult expression to use, an  unpleasant one to read, use and translate in all the various instances of its use.

Comment: dictionary cut and paste without any understanding of the question